spring cloud webflux with http2
I have a spring cloud webflux application, I want my application to work on the http2 protocol.
I create a certificate and keys through Keystore explorer, add them to the configuration of my gateway and microservice:
server:
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:ssl.pfx
    key-store-password: password
    keyStoreType: PKCS12
    key-password: password
    enabled: true
  http2:
    enabled: true

I place the ssl.pfx file in resources, in gateway and in microservice.
But when I make a get request to my microservice through the gateway, I get an error:
2024-06-17T15:22:04.048+03:00  WARN 14896 --- [my-service] [tor-http-nio-10] .s.ApplicationProtocolNegotiationHandler : [id: 0x5853edda, L:/192.168.78.78:54840 - R:/192.168.78.78:56587] Failed to select the application-level protocol:

io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record ....

error on the gateway:
reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]

When I make requests directly to the microservice, via https://.. it works, the h2 protocol is in the browser, but it doesn’t work through the gateway.
Accordingly, I have questions:

What am I doing wrong?
Is it actually possible to make a gateway http2?

There are not many examples, the cloud setting is nowhere to be found, I saw several articles about grpc, but I haven’t tried it yet, in theory you can only get by with h2.

It's certainly possible to use TLS with HTTP2. What type of gateway do you use?

@igor-artamonov, Sorry, I don’t understand the question, what do you mean by what type of gateway?

You said "gateway". I understand this as a standalone application you use to route the API access (such as nginx, envoy, kong, istio, etc). Or what did you mean?

@igor-artamonov, spring gateway, https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway

Ah, I see. Spring has too many projects I guess, never heard about this one before.
